# preparedStatement for a possible null parameter

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a function in kotlin and I am curious if there are ways to make it looks more "clean"?

I have parameters that could be null/optional

```
override fun readByOrderId(orderId: Int, eventType: EventType?, version: Int?): OrderDomain? {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE id=?"
        if(eventType != null)
        {
            sql += " AND eventType=?"
        }

        if(version != null)
        {
            sql += " AND version=?"
        }

        val result: MutableList<OrderDomain> = jdbcTemplate.query<OrderDomain>(
            sql,
            PreparedStatementSetter { preparedStatement -> preparedStatement.setInt(1, orderId)
                preparedStatement.setString(2, eventType.toString())
                preparedStatement.setInt(3, version},
            RowMapper { rs: ResultSet, rowNum: Int ->
                OrderDomain(
                    rs.getLong(DataColumn.EVENT_ID.toString()),
                )
            }
        )
    }
```

But then the placement of the preparedStatement can be an issue, and toString can throw NPE... Is there anything within preparedStatement I could adjust since the two null fields are optional fields?

Comment: Sorry @Tenfour04 they should be optional type, my apologies for the miss

Comment: I don't use JDBC, but I'm assuming that you have to create the SQL string with question marks in place of parameters, and you put the parameters in the PreparedStatement by their index. If this is the case, then if `eventType` is null and `version` isn't, your index numbers will be wrong. It seems you should conditionally add to the prepared statement.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Exactly, that was my concern which I wrote in the second part. I was wondering if there is a way around this except for writing a whole different method for managing null possibilities

Comment: conditions in a where clause are separated using `AND` or `OR`, not with a comma.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yep, caught this in testing, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would conditionally add the appropriate parameters to the statement and keep the indices orderly.

```
PreparedStatementSetter { it.apply {
    var index = 1
    setInt(index++, orderId)
    if (eventType != null) {
        setString(index++, eventType.toString())
    }
    if (version != null) {
        setInt(index++, version)
    }
} }
```

Comment: Interesting though... I didnt think of it that way :o

Answer (score 1):

`null.toString()` in Kotlin [doesn't throw NPE](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html), it returns the string "null".

To avoid explicit parameters indexes declaration, I'd recommend to put all parameters in a list (so that their order in the list matches their order in the query) and use [`setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-) method (so parameters of all types could be handled in a common way):

```kotlin
PreparedStatementSetter {
    val params = listOfNotNull(
        orderId,
        eventType.toString().takeIf { eventType != null },
        version
    )
    params.forEachIndexed { index, param -> it.setObject(index + 1, param) }
}
```

Comment: So this end just compiles a list of all nonnull and put it into the params :? (still trying to figure out kotlin)

Comment: [`listOfNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of-not-null.html) creates a list and filters out all nulls, so that only non-nulls items retained. Afterwards they are set as a query parameters in the same order as they were on a list. Items in list are indexed from 0, and parameters in `PreparedStatement` from 1, so it's adjusted with `index + 1`